# Free loop space of classifying space as a disjoint union of classifying spaces of centralizer proof reference request.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces, loop-spaces

I am looking for a reference for the proof or explanation of why for a discrete group $G$ we have that the free loop space of its classifying space is the disjoint union of centralizeers of $g$ where $[g]$ is the conjugacy class of elements in $G$, or more abbreviated,

$L(BG)= \bigsqcup_{[g]}BC_g$.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88090/the-connected-components-of-the-free-loop-space) by [Craig Westerland](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4649/craig-westerland) gives a proof of the result you want. It uses the following result:
$$L(BG) \simeq G^{ad} \times_G EG$$
for which references are given in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20671/what-is-the-equivariant-cohomology-of-a-group-acting-on-itself-by-conjugation/20677#20677) by [Dan Ramras](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4042/dan-ramras).

Comment: CW because I don't feel like earning rep for quoting MO answers would be fair...